# react-bootstrap-typeahead: How to get attribute value on "OnChange" , I am using Typeahead in table cell

Tags: react-bootstrap-typeahead

I am using react-bootstrap-typeahead in table row for invoice items.

my json is like `[{record_id:1,value="value1"},{record_id:2,value="value2"}]`
on this basis I am creating bootstrap table.
in table cell I am adding typeahead select box to change the value and update my json,

when I change the value I want to update my json array with latest value in related record.
But as in onChange we only get selected array not an event object so, I am not able to find record id.

Answer (score 1):

I have create one solution , I know it is not best but it works for me.
I have set state called currentLineItem and I am updating this value on "onFocus" event of react-bootstrap-typeahead. in this event I am getting an event object.

```
const [currentLineItem, setCurrentLineItem] = useState(null);
const selectBoxOnFocus = (event) => {
    const rowId = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.getAttribute("data-id");
    setCurrentLineItem(rowId);
  };
const taxCalcChangeInRow = async (option) => {
    const rowId = currentLineItem;
    // my other code
  };
<SelectBox {/*(this is wrapper componat of typeahead)*/}
   data-id={row.id}
   name="inputTaxCalc"
   options={taxCalcOptions}
   OnChange={taxCalcChangeInRow}
   onFocus={selectBoxOnFocus}
/>
```